# Install Edimax EW-7612UAn wireless on CentOS 6.5

Tags: software-installation, drivers, wifi, centos

Does anyone know how to install the driver for Edimax EW-7612UAn on CentOS 6.5?

I've tried to install it on Ubuntu, but I never gotten it to work.

EDIT:

Here is an attempt building a downloaded driver from the answer from slm:

```
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64/build M=/home/kristjan/Downloads/RTL8192CU_linux_v3.0.2164.20110715_EDIMAX EW-7612UAn V2/RTL8192CU_8188CUS_8188CE-VAU_linux_v3.0.2164.20110715/driver/rtl8192_8188CU_linux_v3.0.2164.20110715  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `EW-7612UAn'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
Compile make driver error: 2, Please check error Mesg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try downloading the drivers from here? http://www.edimax.com/en/support_download.php?pl1_id=1.

Also I found this thread titled: "[Thread: Driver installation Probrema 7612UAn Edimax EW-v2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2038879)" which covers the compiling and setting up of what looks to be the same card as yours.

Comment: I tried the links in your answer, but to no prevail. The post is from 2009 and the kernel that the driver is for is 2.6. So it doesn't look like I can use this wireless adapter for any of my linux computers:-(

Comment: @somethingSomething - that seems odd to me, usually older hardware has better support on Linux.